# Powerline networking and power surges

Tags: ethernet, powerline-networking

I have a powerline network solution set up. Since powerline networking cant use surge protectors because of the signal degradation, I have to plug it directly into the wall. If there is a surge in the wall, can that surge pass through the ethernet and into my computer or will the surge just break the adapter but not send a surge through the ethernet?

Also do ethernet only surge protectors exist?

Comment: This appears to be theoretically possible at first glance, but is dependent on the specific adapter you are using and the parameters of the surge; you should contact the manufacturer and ask. Be sure to report back if you do, I'd like to hear their response.

Answer (score 0):

A surge can break the adapter and stop there, but might very well pass through the ethernet and into your computer. And yes, you can buy surge protectors for ethernet only.